# LG UltraFine 5K with MacBook Pro 2017 issues

Tags: macbook-pro, display, mojave

Yesterday everything was working fine. I had my MacBook Pro (four USB-C ports & touch bar) connected to my LG UltraFine 5K monitor (official model name: LG 27MD5KA‑B). At the end of my day's work I turned everything off. In the morning I turned everything back on but nothing seemed to work.

I proceeded to disconnect the monitor from the MBP and there the latter turned on without problem. I tried hot-plugging back the monitor and the MBP's screen turned black. Event the touch bar was unresponsive. So I tried all sorts of combinations in order to solve the problem:

- Turn off the MBP, and unplug everything from the mains, wait a moment and reconnect everything;
- MBP [PRAM reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063);
- MBP [SMC reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295);
- Removed all connected peripherals (either directly to the MBP and/or to the monitor);
- Tried all the USB-C ports of the MBP;
- Tried with another touch bar MBP;

One thing that half works is when the LG UltraFine 5K is connected to the mains and I hook an MBP with the lid close. In this case the monitor lits up, although very dimly, I can see the Apple logo and then suddenly the logo is spread horizontally across the screen and lower quarter of the screen is garbled (everything very faint). If I open the lid, only the caps lock seems to work (hinting that the computer has not crashed). If I unhook the MPB it responds without problems after a few seconds. Reconnecting it and the MBP screen turns black and the computer becomes unresponsive (apart from caps lock). I can, however, access the computer through remote login (SSH) and managed to shut it down or restart it from there (`sudo shutdown -h now` or `sudo shutdown -r now`).

I even downloaded the [LG Screen Manager](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lg-screen-manager-lg-monitor/id1142051783?mt=12), but the app seems totally useless in my case (event the copyright notice seems strange showing "Copyright 2016-2026 LG Electronics Inc.").

Any suggestions on what to do next (apart from bringing the apparatus for repair)?

---

System used:

- MBP (13", 2017, 4 thunderbolt-3 ports, Intel Core i5 @ 3.1 GHz, 8GB RAM, Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650 1536 MB);
- MBP (13", 2017, 4 thunderbolt-3 ports, Intel Core i7 @ 3.5 GHz, 16GB RAM, Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650 1536 MB);
- Both MBP are installed with macOS Mojave Version 10.14.2
- LG UltraFine 5K (aka 27MD5KA‑B);

Comment: Try these things first and report back: (1) Plug the monitor into a port on the other side of the MBP, (2) Remove all other connected units on the MBP and monitor - i.e. USB devices, etc., (3) Try with a different cable - note it must be a Thunderbolt 3 cable capable of supporting 5 amps.

Comment: @jksoegaard. Thank you very much for your comment. As a matter of fact I tried all your suggestions but the cable. Will buy one ASAP and try it out. (Will also update my post in order to reflect the things I did but forgot to mention.)

Comment: Everything here, especially the part where you tried another MBP, points to a failed LG monitor.  It's not unheard of.  It's time to call LG support on this one.

Comment: @Allan. Yes you are right. The only thing I will try before doing that is what jksoegaard suggested: another USB-C to USB-C >5A cable…

Comment: You mean a USB-IF certified cable.  But why?  Are you trying to charge your MBP off the LG?  If so, is it charging? The symptom of the image being "dim" is consistent with a back light issue, not a cable.

Comment: @Allan hopefully the cable will be USB-IF certified. In any case it needs to be of USB-C format. Characteristics can be found in [this document] (https://bit.ly/2FpfxWE) page 37. I think Apple calls it Thunderbolt 3 (e.g., [Thunderbolt 3 (USB‑C) Cable (0.8 m)] (https://apple.co/2H8f9hA)). Yes, the monitor charges the MBP (it is one of its [features] (https://apple.co/2FiBKGp), under "Product Information" section **Tech Specs**, 6th line). As whether the MBP is charging or not, I don't know because both screens turn black (and the MBP becomes unresponsive) when I connect it to the monitor.

Comment: @Allan. Sorry, I have to split my answer in 2 messages. Regarding the dimming, this does only occur when I start the computer from a complete shutdown with the lid closed. If the lid is open, both screens are entirely black (no backlight). In any case the computer becomes unresponsive. However, it does not freeze (as in an OS crash) because as soon as it is unplugged from the monitor normal operation resumes (it is like if the computer went into sleep mode). Therefore, I venture to say that the issue I have is not of the dimming nature.

Comment: I had all kinds of wacky issues using LG 21" 4K and 27" 5K with a 13" MBP (2016) and a 15" MBP with TouchBar (2017).  One out of four of the 21" was faulty within three months of purchase, one of the 27" would only work with one single cable.  Great display quality but entirely too unreliable.

Comment: @da4. Sad to read you had so many issues with your LG monitors. On my side it has been working reliably for the last year and a half. Will call LG on Monday to see what can be done. Will keep the thread posted.

Comment: Just to give you an update. Friday I went to the Apple store an bought a Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 3 cable and the result was the same as for the original LG cable. So I guess only option that remains is to call LG service. Will keep the thread posted.

Comment: @pdeli I also found the LG utility for macOS basically useless, but if you have an available Windows system it might be worth checking for firmware updates.

Comment: I have this same exact issue. I have tried all the things that @pdeli listed and I also tried a new Thunderbolt 3 display cable. No luck. I tried plugging it into a LG UltraFine monitor at the Apple Store and it worked there. I'm going to contact LG now...

Comment: @senornestor, I had to send mine to LG and they allegedly changed the motherboard of the monitor. Works fine since then. I just hope that it will not break down again just after the warranty is worn out…

anyways, good luck with yours.

Comment: @pdeli Yes, mine is already out-of-warranty so I will need to take it to an authorized repair shop. I bought another used one Craigslist the other day and it works but it seems like if I touch the display cable attaching my Mac and the monitor, the display will cut out and I have to unplug and replug to get it back. My conclusion: This is a buggy monitor and I wouldn't recommend it to anyone, but it's one of the USB-C monitors on the market ‍♂️️

Answer (score 1):

It sounds weird but anothet thing to try is if you have the Macbook touching the LG5K display in any way it causes some sort of earthing issue.  As you know the Macbook aluminium case is a conductor and there are minute amounts of current generated on the shell by the Macbook Pro itself.  If these currents find their way to the LG5K display it causes erratic behaviour (display turns off for a second or two) or wavy lines.

Also pls be aware not all Type-C's are the same - a Type C1 (TH3 mode) passes a 5K display signal whereas a Type C2 (USB3.1) does not.